# Link to a part inside an external HTML page

Tags: html

The default way to jump to somewhere in a HTML page is use the a href/a name tags. However, if I want to refer to an external website, somewhere in the middle and that external page does not use the a name tag, is there an alternative way? Like jumping to the first occurrence of some text?

Comment: Do you want it to be done from your website? The source one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need a:

```
<a name="named-anchor"></a>
```

Find the nearby element with an `id` attribute. For eg., consider this:

```
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04
```

The site has:

```
<h2 id="prerequisites">Prerequisites</h2>
```

So you can go to that place, by adding `#` and the `id` value:

```
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04#prerequisites
```

If that's not there, then it is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible unless the external website has any custom support for it and they don't have `name` or `id` in the desired location.

Answer (score 1):

It's only possible if you find element with ID at the place of where to jump, than simply apply `#id-of-element` to link.

E.g. We have [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes) HTML attributes list and want to link to `lang` attribute.
Inspect element and we find `<dt id="attr-lang">` than link would be [`https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-lang`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-lang)

Answer (score 1):

If one of the elements on the site which your are trying to link to has an **id** attached to it.

You can force the load of the page onto that specific element by adding a hashtag at the end of the url of the website, and the name of the **id** for that specific element.

For example:

```
<a href="https://yourdomain.com/page#element_to_jump_to">Click me!</a>
```

Try clicking this clicking this link just here:

[Link to a part inside an external HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41464075/link-to-a-part-inside-an-external-html-page/41464200#footer)

You will notice that it brings you to the **footer** section of this `StackOverflow` post.

However, other than that there are no other possible ways of achieving this (at least as far as Google knows)